# Stream and response callbacks fire arbitrarily

Tags: node.js, stream, httpresponse

I am a node.js beginner. I am trying to write a simple http server which serves a file specified on the console on the given port.

let http = require('http');
let fs = require('fs');

let server = http.createServer((request, response) => {

```
let fileStream = fs.createReadStream(process.argv[3]);
fileStream.pipe(response);

fileStream.on('end', () => {
  console.log('Stream ended.'); // 1
  response.end(() => {
    console.log('Response ended.'); // 2
  });
}); 
});

server.listen(process.argv[2]);
```

While the first `console.log('Stream ended')` is written twice to the console when I send a request with my browser, the second `console.log('Response ended.)` is never called, even though everything in my .txt file has been send to the browser.

I would expect both to show up, once.

I couldn't find any info on this in the official documentation, but does pipe() end the response automatically? Why is console.log #1 fired twice?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why did you place `response.end` inside of fileStream.on? It probably behaves normally if not being done like that. *Why is console.log #1 fired twice?* - there's a number of similar questions. I suppose one that there are 2 requests from a browser, and one of them is favicon. Logging a request could help.

Comment: If I put the response.end() outside of the fileStream end event listener, I cannot control when it is called - now it is called when I have written everything there was from the stream to the response, thus, when the end event is fired on the stream. Is this not the right way to do it?

Thank you for the console.log #1 explanation! That makes sense.

Comment: I see what you mean. response.end callback isn't triggered because it's already ended when fileStream is ended. You don't need response.end() here at all.